# How to share data between javascript files without database using import - export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a login page with react without using javascript. For that I need to export my javascript file where my "data" is stored manually, and apply a map function on it to get back the value I'm looking for, in order to confirm my ids.
I didn't success to get back the value from my js file.
I don't know if it's a importing problem or my find function is not well writing.

This is a react project using javascript files as local storage.

```
export default[

    {
        id: 1,
        firtst_name: 'ajax',
        last_name: 'ajaxi',
        email: 'ajax@ajaxi.com',
        password: '123456',
        is_admin: false,

    },
];
```

```
import users from "./users.js";
```

```
function valide (user){
  return user.name === 'ajax';
  }
```

I have no error message when I run.

Comment: React is a javascript library, so I'm not sure what you mean by "react without using javascript". Can you show how `valide(user)` is being called? It also looks like you're checking for a user property called `name` but I don't see that property in your example user object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the data as *const*

```
export const data = [
{
    id: 1,
    firtst_name: 'ajax',
    last_name: 'ajaxi',
    email: 'ajax@ajaxi.com',
    password: '123456',
    is_admin: false,
},
];
```

and 
`import data from "./data"`

The *const* should be available which you can use in function for validation